# Send database email based on "if body content true send / false don't send"

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to send an email based on  "if body content true send / false don't send"
It doesn't have to be that it can be if there's something returned send if nothing returned don't send.
My code is based on a post from : https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83776/need-to-send-a-formatted-html-email-via-database-mail-in-sql-server-2008-r2

If you find this code a bit of a mess its the one the question owner accepted as the best answer at the above link.
Using MS SQL Server 2014

```
SET @Body = ( SELECT    td = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), P.Date, 120), '',
                    td = P.ID, '',
                    td = P.ID2, '',
                    td = G.ID, '',
                    td = D.ID,'',
                    td = D.Name,'',
                    td = CASE WHEN G.SubmittedDate IS NULL THEN 'New'
                              ELSE 'Dealer Submitted'
                         END, ''
          FROM      I_CancelledGRN I
                    INNER JOIN TxnGRN G ON G.ID = I.ID
                    INNER JOIN Distributor D ON D.UID = G.DistributorUID
                    INNER JOIN POTxn P ON P.SiteUID = G.POTxn_SiteUID
                                          AND P.UID = G.POTxnUID
          WHERE IsCancelled IS NULL
        FOR   XML RAW('tr'),
              ELEMENTS
        )




SELECT  @Body = @TableHead + ISNULL(@Body, '') + @TableTail

EXEC sp_send_dbmail 
      @profile_name='DatabaseEmailProfile',
      @copy_recipients ='aasc@stackexchange.com',
      @recipients='aa.sc@outlook.com'
      @subject='Query Result',
      @body=@Body ,
      @body_format = 'HTML' ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would something like this work for you?

```
SET @Body = ( SELECT    td = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), P.Date, 120), '',
                    td = P.ID, '',
                    td = P.ID2, '',
                    td = G.ID, '',
                    td = D.ID,'',
                    td = D.Name,'',
                    td = CASE WHEN G.SubmittedDate IS NULL THEN 'New'
                              ELSE 'Dealer Submitted'
                         END, ''
          FROM      I_CancelledGRN I
                    INNER JOIN TxnGRN G ON G.ID = I.ID
                    INNER JOIN Distributor D ON D.UID = G.DistributorUID
                    INNER JOIN POTxn P ON P.SiteUID = G.POTxn_SiteUID
                                          AND P.UID = G.POTxnUID
          WHERE IsCancelled IS NULL
        FOR   XML RAW('tr'),
              ELEMENTS
        )


IF LEN(@Body) > 0
BEGIN

SELECT  @Body = @TableHead + ISNULL(@Body, '') + @TableTail

EXEC sp_send_dbmail 
      @profile_name='DatabaseEmailProfile',
      @copy_recipients ='aasc@stackexchange.com',
      @recipients='aa.sc@outlook.com'
      @subject='Query Result',
      @body=@Body ,
      @body_format = 'HTML' ;

END
```

It just checks weather @Body has any length at all, and only sends the mail if it does. You can use any other evaluation instead of LEN depending on your scenario

Comment: Believe it or not that is exactly what I came up with in the end, not just saying it had more trouble getting the html format right :-( but works now , many thanks' for your reply :-)